# How to return a collection of objects only after they have been filled from a long process

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, event-handling

I have a database of objects from a 3rd party SDK.  They offer an event based approach to searching for things. I wish to search for things and only return the results after the search has completed. Here is the pseudo code I'm working with:

```
Class SearchThings
{
    private Object DatabaseOfDifferentThings;
    
    private List<Thing> _objects = null;
    private SearchSession _search = null;
    private bool _initialized = false;
    
    public SearchThings()
    {
        
    }
    
    Public List<thing> GetFoundThings()
    {
        if (_initialized == false)
        {
            StartSearch();  
        }
        
        return _objects;
    }
    
    private void StartSearch()
    {
        _objects = new List<Thing>();
        _search = DatabaseOfDifferentThings("TypeOfThingToSearchFor");
        _search.ThingAvailable += OnThingAvailable;
        _search.Progress += OnProgress;
        
        _search.StartSearch();
    }
    
    private void OnThingAvailable(Thing thing)
    {
        _objects.Add(thing);
    }
    
    private void OnProgress(int progress)
    {
        if (progress == 100)
        {
            _search.StopSearch();
            _search -= OnProgress;
            _search -= OnThingAvailable;
            
            _initialized = true;
        }
    }

}
```

My intent is to only return from GetFoundThings() when the List is fully populated and initialized. Since the searching mechanism subscribes to events to fill the List, I am unsure of how to use async await or another mechanism to "pause" while the objects are being gathered.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Example of usage:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
```

change `StartSearch` to return `Task`

```
private Task StartSearch()
{
    _objects = new List<Thing>();
    _search = DatabaseOfDifferentThings("TypeOfThingToSearchFor");
    _search.ThingAvailable += OnThingAvailable;
    _search.Progress += OnProgress;
    
    _search.StartSearch();
    return _tcs.Task; // return Task that represents future work
}
```

then in your `OnProgress` when it has hit `100`, you can complete the `Task`

```
private void OnProgress(int progress)
{
    if (progress == 100)
    {
        _search.StopSearch();
        _search -= OnProgress;
        _search -= OnThingAvailable;
        
        _initialized = true;
        _tcs.SetResult(null);
    }
}
```

and then you can call it like so:

```
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetFoundThings()
{
    if (_initialized == false)
    {
       await StartSearch();  
    }
    
    return _objects;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JohanP, that worked well. Save me a lot of pain.